# how to make a responsive canvas for google map in ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic2

In this code, I am trying to make map canvas fit to below of box but it seems `auto` value is not acceptable for the `map element`.

**map.ts**

```
initializeMap() {
    let minZoomLevel = 16;
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: minZoomLevel,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(this.map);
    });
}
```

Html has a box under navbar to define Origin and Target of delivery service:

**map.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-80>
       <ion-item> <ion-label >Origin:</ion-label> <ion-input  [value]="Origin" ></ion-input> </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col> 

  <button ion-button icon-only icon-left (click)="OriginMarker()"  color="light"><ion-icon name="locate" ></ion-icon> </button>    
 </ion-col>  
</ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-80>
       <ion-item> <ion-label >Target: </ion-label> <ion-input  [value]="Target"></ion-input> </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col> 
    <button ion-button icon-only icon-left (click)="TargetMarker()" color="secondary"><ion-icon name="locate" ></ion-icon> </button>
 </ion-col>  
</ion-row>
<ion-row>
    <ion-col width-75>
<button ion-button block outline color="secondary" large >Start Delivery </button>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
 <ion-label>cost: <br>{{price}} </ion-label>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**map.scss**

```
page-map {
    #map_canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
}
```

Any of width and height properties are not accepting `auto` value.

**update :** 1st screenshot shows `height :auto;`:
[image]

**update:** 2nd screenshot when using  `height :100%;`:
[image]

as you can see above when using `100%` it make additional page which is out of screen and then needs to be scroold

Comment: Could you please, also share the screenshot of the UI.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni I add updates. in second photo you can see it needs to be scrolled down and 100% is make page bigger than screen.